# Diagonals of a parallelogram

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, area, quadrilateral

The diagonals of a parallelogram are $8$ and $4$. They meet at $60°$.  Find the sides and area of the parallelogram.

---

I tried to use the cosine rule here having $4$ and $2$ as the sides and $60°$ as the angle. But the answer I got is different than the answer key. Also, what about the area and the other two sides?

One side = $\sqrt{20-16\cos60°} = 3.46$

The other side I got is $5.29$

And, what should we use to calculate the area? $ab\sin x$?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show what you did and what the answer key says. And try to find the area and the other two sides (whatever that means) rather than tagging on your "what about" question.

Comment: Did you evaluate $\cos(60^\circ)$?

Comment: Can you evaluate one side in terms of radicals?

Comment: You say that the diagonals "meet at 60 degrees" but two intersecting lines form **four** angles.  Two of the angles are 60 degrees to the other two 120 degrees.  Yes, the cosine law for a triangle with sides of  2 and 4 and angle between them 60 degrees will give the length of two sides.  (Surely, you didn't make the mistake of using 4 and 8?)  Then use the cosine law with a triangle with sides of length 2 and 4 and angle between them 120 degrees to find the other two sides.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can calculate the area directly by noticing the diagonals bisect each other, as shown in the image above.

Then notice that the triangles opposite each other are also congruent, again by ASA. One pair of the triangles has an angle of $60º$, and the other pair has an angle of $120º$. Thus the area of the parallelogram is $2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}(4)(2) \sin 60º + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} (4)(2) \sin 120º = 8\sqrt{3}$.